# Append List of FilesTo Binary

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, environment-variables

Is there a way to append a list of files as an executable to the file itself such that the file is still executable?

For example let's say I have 2 files file1 and file2.  How might I append the the files in a way to the binary.  Again this is a simple example, I would like to have a cross Operating System way to extract Unix and Windows files.  Cross operating system way to append zips (or tar.gz) to a file only to extract it later.

The following illustrates how the files might be extracted and or created.

```
create ./a.exe ./output.exe file1 file2

extract output.exe
```

## Downvoters please leave comments

```
copy /b test.exe+test.txt testwithtext.exe
cp /bin/ls test;cat /etc/hosts >> trst
```

Comment: Why do you want that? what is the use case?

Comment: @iharob one file which contains both the binary and source code is simple convenient.

Comment: Convinient for what?

Comment: @iharob I don't want to have to worry about a package manager or source manager.

Comment: Why would you have to worry about a package manager or source manager?

Comment: @immibis source code manager `git` or `mercurial` for example.  I don't want to have to worry version tracking.

Comment: Crazy to reject revision control

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not. Technically I am just looking for a way to distribute binaries with the source code attached.

Comment: Don't pack it in the exe. How will anyone extract it? Wrap exe and source in a container. tar.gz or zip or similar.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you believe the question should be closed vote to close.  The question has been partially answered.  Both `cat /etc/hosts >> foo` and `copy /b test.exe+test.txt testwithtext.exe` are shown to work you just need a way to extract/ read the data out backwards.

Comment: The question is fine. I'm just offering my opinion that you are doing something ill advised. Inventing your own container format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you could accomplish this by attaching the source as an extra unused section in the binary. For instance, on Linux (or other ELF systems using GNU binutils), we could embed this in a `source` section:

```
objcopy yes --add-section source=yes.c yes
```

and to extract it:

```
objcopy yes --only-section source --set-section-flags source=alloc -O binary yes.c
```

Similarly, on Mac OS X, we can pass some extra options to the linker to have it create the section:

```
gcc -Wl,-sectcreate,source,yes.c,yes.c yes.c -o yes
```

(Note that the source file name shows up twice in the linker option; this is not a typo! Sections in a Mach-O executable have both a segment and a section name; I'm using the filename as the section name here.)

and to extract it:

```
otool -s source yes.c -X yes
```

(This unfortunately gives output as a hexdump, rather than raw data. You'll have to massage it a bit to get it back to text.)

---

That being said, this is all incredibly silly. **Don't use this as a serious method of distributing source code.** Embedding the source in an executable is a party trick, not a useful technique.

Comment: What about a folder (zip or tar.gz)?

Comment: Substitute the name of the archive for the name of the source file. Same principle applies.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux and (which uses the ELF file format for executables) and Mac OS X (which uses Mach-O), and some other systems, you can simply append data to an executable and it will still run.  For example:

```
cp /bin/ls foo
cat /etc/hosts >> foo
./foo
```

This will run just like `ls` but the file also contains a text file at the end.

Comment: And Mac OSX I'm assuming.  In addition couldn't you use tar to append a folder?

Comment: I have edited the question because I would like this to work in Windows, and it appears this doesn't work in Cygwin.

Comment: @William: appending arbitrary data to a Windows executable seems to work fine for me.  (I don't have Cygwin installed, so that might be different, though I'm not sure why it would be.)  Have you tried `copy /b test.exe+test.txt testwithtext.exe` ?

Comment: If you have a cross OS way I will gladly accept.  I'm not certain though from your given answer how you would go about retrieving the information once it is added.  @HarryJohnston  Yes it possible that cygwin is causing unknown issues.  I will try another example.

Comment: @William: once you've confirmed that appending extra data to the executable file doesn't affect its functioning, actually doing so is a trivial programming exercise.  Retrieving it (efficiently) is a bit trickier, because you need to work out what the size of the executable part of the file is, which depends on the format.  If it doesn't have to be efficient, just put a null character (or anything else that doesn't appear in the source) at the beginning and read the file from the end backwards until you find it.

Comment: The resulting executable isn't valid. It may *happen to run* on some systems, but it's also possible that it will be rejected by some systems.

Comment: @duskwuff: in what way is it not valid?  Under ELF or Mach-O?  Can you be more specific about your concerns?

Comment: @JohnZwinck The appended data ends up not being part of any described section of the file. I suppose it may not be syntactically *wrong*, but it's not really meaningful either. (Trying to codesign a Mach-O executable of this type will almost certainly fail, though.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a program to read the source code file
  1. Write it to convert line breaks into escaped characters and deal with quotes and other such characters
  2. Write it to output it as a character array embedded in an appropriate place in the source code and written out as a new file.
2. Configure your maker/builder to call the rewriter program to create the new file and then compile and build from the new file.

Note:  This does not meet the strict requirement that the code be "appended" nor a (possible but unstated) requirement that it be "as-is" and unescaped.

Does it have to be C?  Question text does not say the language, though the tag implies it.

If it were Java, you would just build a jar which would have the "executable" and the source as two files in the jar which is itself executable.

Comment: Yes C java is interpreted language therefore it defeats my intentions.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create an executable file that will accept the list of paths to the executables to be run in sequence .

eg:runall /home/a.exe /home/output.exe

Answer (score 0):

Just pack them inside a zip. ZIP is a cross platform container that can contain multiple files.

This is really the best solution to your problem.

You can also use a [self extracting archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) using some archiving tool like 7-zip. That is the fastest way to get two executables inside another executable.